# Heartbeat with Alarmmanger doesn't keep service alive

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, heartbeat

In may App I need a Service to run constantly in the backround. I tried to manage this with a Heartbeat with a Alarmmanager. It calls every 15min a AlarmReceive class that stops and then starts again my Backround Service. 
But the system shuts everything down, when the device doesn't get used for a longer time (mostly over night)
here is my code (MainActivity):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.e("Alarmmanager", "Starting Alarmmanager");
    if (alarmManager == null && !isMyServiceRunning(BackroundService.class)) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 900000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And the AlarmReceive:

```
public class AlarmReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent background = new Intent(context, BackroundService.class);
    context.stopService(background);
    context.startService(background);

}
}
```

Could you help me fixing this problem?
I need this service to rum all time. 
Thanks, Slarti.

Comment: In need this service to be allive. Otherwise my App is senseless. The service only works if the screen is turned on. If the screen is turned off, there is no process going on (it' in a empty loop then).

Comment: yes, I start it in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to post my service, that should run in the backround:

```
public class BackroundService extends Service {

boolean isDestroy;



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.e("New Service","################STARTED#################");

    isDestroy = false;

    //code for letting the service run even if app is not used
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // For foreground service
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BackroundService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        // Creating channel for notification
        String id = BackroundService.class.getSimpleName();
        String name = BackroundService.class.getSimpleName();
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(id,
                name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        NotificationManager service = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        service.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        // Foreground notification
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this, id)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("KSL is protecting you!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker("Ticker text")
                .build();

        startForeground(9, notification);
    }

    //here is my locationlistener that's doing something with the gps updates



    return START_STICKY;
}



//this method request the gps location every 500 milliseconds, but only if the screen is turned on
public void requestingGpsUpdates(){
    powerManager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    //Handler to delay
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void run() {
        if (powerManager.isScreenOn()){
            Log.d("Requesting:","GpsLocation");
            //asking for a new update
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //removing the update from before
                    Log.e("Updates:","removed");
                    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                }
            },500);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, locationListener);
        }else{
            //if screen is turned off updates will be removed
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
        //the method calling itself for a loop
            if (!isDestroy){
                requestingGpsUpdates();
            }else {
            Log.e("Service", "get's destroyed!");
            }
        }
    },500);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    isDestroy = true;
}
```

}